# Angular: Getting the last 4 posts from Contentful

Tags: angular5, angular-promise, redux-observable, contentful

Hi I'm trying to get the last four blog posts from contentful api in angular 5. I've created a service and I'm capable of retrieving 1 with the following code.

```
getContent(contentId) {
   const promise = this.client.getEntry(contentId);
   return Observable.fromPromise(promise).map(entry => entry.fields);
};
```

I would like to return it as an observable, however if returned as a promise, I would like to know how to work with a promise in the component.ts and -.html.

```
getLastByCount(number) {
   var promise = this.client.getEntries({
       limit: number
   })
   ...
}
```

If i do the same for getting multiple entries I get a 'PromiseObservable', which contains a 'promise: ZoneAwarePromise'. In which it has 'items: Array', where object are as when i log the single entry. How do I work which such objects?

Edited:

I've done as suggested by: Stephan

```
getLastByCount(number) {
   var promise = this.client.getEntries({
   limit: number
   })
   return Observable.fromPromise(promise).mergeMap((collection) => (
     Observable.from(collection.items)
   ))
}
```

And in my component.ts in OnInit()

```
posts$: Observable<any>;

this.posts$ = this.contentfulService.getLastByCount(4).map(entry => entry.fields);
```

In my component.html, i do this when displaying the one entry

```
<div *ngIf="post$ | async as post">
   <h1>{{ post.headline }}</h1>
   <time>Published on {{ post.published | date: 'fullDate'  }}</time>
   <hr>-->
</div>
```

I try this when using the collection:

```
<div *ngIf="posts$ | async as posts">
  <ul>
   <li class="post" *ngFor="let post of posts$ | async">
   <h1>{{ post.headline }}</h1>
   <time>Published on {{ post.published | date: 'fullDate'  }}</time>
   <hr>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I get this error: Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is an Observable that emits every single `item` of the collection that the Contentful client returns.

To do so, you can use the `mergeMap` functionality:

```
Observable
  .fromPromise(promise)
  .mergeMap((collection) => (
    Rx.Observable.from(collection.items)
  ))
```

Now you can work with every item in the observable sequence as with the single entry above, e.g. you can

```
.map(entry => entry.fields)
```

EDIT:

Turns out Angular expects you to have an `Observable<Entry[]>`, instead of `Observable<Entry>`, so the proper way is:

```
Observable
  .fromPromise(promise)
  .map((collection) => collection.items)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It brought me a little further, but I can't display it still. Please see my edits, where I've provided more code to fully see what I want to do. Thank you :)

Comment: I'm not that firm with Angular (my suggestion was just about Observables), but according to https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/http-with-observables/ you want to have an Observable that emits an array of items, so you can get rid of the `mergeMap` & `Observable.from` and just do a plain `map(({ items }) => items)`

Comment: I ended up using promises instead of Observables that works fine.